# Mysql: Index по сумме столбцов

Tags: mysql, index

Всем привет.

Недавно начал изучать индексы в mysql. Столкнулся со следующем вопросом, ответ на который найти не смог.
Есть запрос на выборку, в котором учавствует условие по сумме столбцов, скажем:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE (col1+col2) > 100
```

Как правильно создать индекс для данного условия **(col1+col2)**?
Я предположил, что можно сделать это так:

```
CREATE INDEX col1col2 ON table1(col1+col2);
```

Но есть сомнения в правильности такой записи.
Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нет, так сделать нельзя. Просто невозможно применить арифметическую операцию при создании индекса.

если ОЧЕНЬ нужно, ты можешь сделать новую колонку, которую ты будешь апдейтить значениями col1+col2 и сделать ее индексом.

значения > N выбирать по ней.

можно сделать составной индекс (col1,col2), но он будет медленней, чем индекс по колонке, в которой уже хранится сумма.

```
create table v (a int, b int, key (a,b));
insert into v values(1,2);
explain select  a+b from v;

+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | NULL       | index | NULL          | a    | 10      | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+

alter table v drop index a;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

explain select  a+b from v;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
```

обратите внимание на разницу в двух EXPLAIN

Все зависит от ваших требований.

- Без (составного) индекса - адище.
- С составным индексом - лучше. // смотрите постскриптум, возможно, я не совсем прав, зависит от запроса
- С новой колонкой - больше потерь по hdd и медленнее при вставке данных, но гораздо быстрее при чтении.

P.S. еще больше зависит от запроса, посмотрите ответ @Firepro и комментарии к нему.

Comment: Только он при сумме все равно не поможет, правильно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский к сожалению, MySQL, в отличие от того же PostgreSQL не поддерживает индексацию выражений. Вы можете проиндексировать только столбец.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский при суммировании может помочь, это можно проверить, кстати. Имхо лучше новую колонку сделать.

Comment: Составной индекс у меня есть, вот были сомнения, что он пригоден.
Получается решением остается только создание новой колонки.
Что ж, спасибо, что пролили свет :)

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, в MySQL нет поддержки индексов на условия, как это есть в PostgreSQL.

Создание составного индекса на col1 и col2 ускорит общее время выполнения запроса, т.к данные извлекаются быстрее, но если Вы будете использовать в запросе другие поля, скорее всего встроенный оптимизатор примет решение о полном сканировании таблицы.

Comment: мы проверили, и составной индекс  _используется_.

Comment: Я не говорил о том, что индекс не используется. Он не ускорит обработку операции сложения, а лишь поможет выбрать значения для данной операции, чтобы не сканировать всю строку, если среди col1 и col2, есть еще колонки. На старом Pentium, 1000000 операций сложения выполняется за 0,3 с.

Comment: ну, все-таки ускорит, поскольку поможет выбрать значения. если вы отредактируете ответ, я с вами соглашусь.

Comment: Индексы для этого и предназначены)) Но в данном случае, только если SELECT связан с col1 и col2, если вы делаете SELECT col1, col2, name, last_name, first_name WHERE col1+col2>100, то скорее всего, встроенный оптимизатор будет использовать полное сканирование, без индекса.

Comment: А вы правы. `explain select a+b from  y force index(a)  where (a+b)  > 1;`  только так я смог получить `Using where; Using index`, `explain select a+b, y.c from  y force index(a)  where (a+b)  > 1;` его уже не использует